# Passing shell variable to awk does not produce expected output

Tags: shell, awk

I'm trying to output a set of variables into a CSV formatted string, e.g.,

```
a11-ai-001,Gi1/0/28,207,f8b1.56d1.ff64,Dell,10.76.207.47,DHCP_Allocated,USHAGWITV102
```

Using the following code:

```
echo $switch | awk '{ print "switch="$1 }'
echo $accessport | awk '{ print "accessport="$1 }'
echo $accessvlan | awk '{ print "accessvlan="$1 }'
echo $mac | awk '{ print "mac="$1 }'
echo $macvendor | awk '{ print "macvendor="$1 }'
echo $ip | awk '{ print "ip="$1 }'
echo $ipstate | awk '{ print "ipstate="$1 }'
echo $hostname | awk '{ print "hostname="$1 }'

echo $switch $accessport $accessvlan $mac $macvendor $ip $ipstate $hostname  | awk -v '{ print $1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6" "$7" "$8 }'

awk -v var1="$switch" -v var2="$accessport" -v var3="$accessvlan" -v > var4="$mac" -v var5="$macvendor" -v var6="$ip" -v var7="$ipstate" -v > var8="$hostname" 'BEGIN{print > var1","var2","var3","var4","var5","var6","var7","var8 }'
```

I receive this output:

> switch=a11-ai-001
>   accessport=Gi1/0/28
>   accessvlan=207
>   mac=f8b1.56d1.ff64
>   macvendor=Dell
>   ip=10.76.207.47
>   ipstate=DHCP_Allocated
>   hostname=USHAGWITV102
>   ,USHAGWITV102001,Gi1/0/28,207,f8b1.56d1.ff64,Dell,10.76.207.47,DHCP_Allocated
>   ,USHAGWITV102001,Gi1/0/28,207,f8b1.56d1.ff64,Dell,10.76.207.47,DHCP_Allocated

When what I want is this:

> switch=a11-ai-001
>   accessport=Gi1/0/28
>   accessvlan=207
>   mac=f8b1.56d1.ff64
>   macvendor=Dell
>   ip=10.76.207.47
>   ipstate=DHCP_Allocated
>   hostname=USHAGWITV102
>   a11-ai-001,Gi1/0/28,207,f8b1.56d1.ff64,Dell,10.76.207.47,DHCP_Allocated,USHAGWITV102
>   a11-ai-001,Gi1/0/28,207,f8b1.56d1.ff64,Dell,10.76.207.47,DHCP_Allocated,USHAGWITV102

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `awk` code is wrong syntactically, I doubt if it produced an output as you claim. What is your input and what is your expected output?

Comment: Why are you using `awk` at all? `echo "$switch,$accessport,$accessvlan,..."`

Comment: Thanks chepner, it was the trailing carriage return, got rid of that and got the output I was trying for. I can't remember why I was using awk, it worked until I added the ipstate variable, so I'd left it at that until then. If you looked at my code, you'd probably have a lot more "why are you doing that?" questions. ;) Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The value of `ipstate` ends with a carriage return, which when "displayed" moves the cursor to the beginning of the line. The rest of `awk`'s output then overwrites the text at the beginning of the line. You can fix this at the point of the problem

```
awk ... -v var7="${ipstate%$'\r'}" ...
```

or handle it when the value of `ipstate` is first assigned.

Comment: A question on how to identify something trivial as `\r` from just OP's output? Is it just the possible hypotheses? or some commands to find, like `hexdump`?

Comment: Note the lack of a comma following `DHCP_ALLOCATED` and the presence of that comma and the value of `$hostname` at the *beginning* of the line. This is a very common error; it's the first thing we ask posters to check for in the tag wiki (if only anyone would ever read that).

Comment: That's great stuff! will rem this from now!